# Google Script to add Asana Task Error 400

Tags: google-apps-script, asana-api

I am using the following example to attempt creation of Asana task via Google Sheets script.

Referencing this SO question and accepted answer.
[Creating Asana tasks from Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30188226/creating-asana-tasks-from-google-apps-script)

The OP claimed it worked at the time, in 2015. Now, I am receiving the following error after attempting to debug with my own private key, etc.

Asana's site has decent documentation on the API, but no examples of properly formatted JSON to reference...as far as I can tell.

I have added this script to my google sheet and receive the error below while attempting to debug the testTask() using my own PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN, WORKSPACE_ID, and ASSIGNEE.

```
Request failed for app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"errors":[{"message":"Could not parse request data, invalid JSON","help":"For more information on API status codes and how to handle them, read th... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 98, file "Code")
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you are running into this issue because the payload you are sending to Asana is actually not formatted correctly. I'd be able to help you figure out what is wrong with it if you can post the actual payload you are sending to Asana. The best way you can do this is to create a curl request to Asana.

This page should have examples (with json) to get you started: https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/input-output-options

My best guess is you might have some extra " characters or a missing , that cause your json to become invalid.

It is very difficult to help you without a concrete example of what isn't working for you. Good luck!

Comment: I have the exact same issue, I posted a SO question and I provided my code. Could you please have a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43060610/creating-an-asana-task-using-a-post-http-request