# How to set custom_fields that has an enum_value using a POST HTTP request?

Tags: asana, asana-api

I'm trying to set a custom_fields of **type enum_value** in a task that I'm creating with a POST HTTP request.

I managed to set a custom_field of **type number** but I'm having issue with the **custom_fields** of **type enum_value**

Questions:

Here's what I did so far:

1- I created the custom_fields that I want to populate on asana, I can set custom_fields of **type number** but not the ones of **type enum_value**( see picture attached)

[image]

Here's my code (I tried different implementations to set the custom_fields that were incorrect) :

```
  var task = {
      data: {
        assignee: "me",
        workspace: "1234567", 
        projects: "9876543",
        parent: null,
        custom_fields: {
          "1234567898": 333,  // this works
          "98765": "Public" // this custom field holds an enum_values, this implementation doesn't work
        },
        notes: "Test notes" 
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you put the name of the enum_value instead of the id.  Here is an example of a PUT/POST request and response:

```
# Request
curl --request PUT -H "Authorization: Bearer <personal_access_token>" \
https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks/1001 \

    -d
    '{
      "data": {
        "custom_fields":{
          "124578":"439"
        }
      }
    }'

    # Response
    {
      "data": {
        "id": 1001,
        "name": "Hello, world!",
        "completed": false,
        "...": "...",
        "custom_fields": [
          {
            "id": 124578,
            "name": "Priority",
            "type": "enum",
            "enum_value": {
              "id": 439,
              "name": "High",
              "enabled": true,
              "color": "red"
            }
          },
          "~..."
        ]
      }
    }
```

It's admittedly a bit buried, but if you look in the [Custom Fields section](https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/custom-fields) of the getting started documentation, there is an example of creating custom fields under "Accessing Custom Field values on Tasks".